# Trying to call an element in a 2-d array in a while loop (python/numpy)

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I am trying to create a program that reduces any given matrix to reduced row echelon form.

What I'm trying to is to divide each entry in the row by the leading number. For example, say I have:

```
[ [3, 4, 5], [ 1, 2, 3] ]  # a 2-d array. which gives:

[ 3, 4, 5]
[ 1, 2, 3]
```

I'm trying to turn that into [ 1 , 4/3, 5/3]. However, if you follow my code:

```
def npgauss(a):
    n = 0

    for i in a[0]:
        x = a[0][0] 
        a[0][n] = a[0][n]/x 
        print a[0][n]
        n = n + 1
```

you'll see that my problem is that the 1st entry get divided by itself to give 1, and then when it goes to the second entry, it divides that by the new number 1 instead of the original number 3 (which is what I want).

I can't figure out a way around this! How do I make it so that it divides by the original number?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of numerical computation, you might want to look at the numpy and scipy.linalg modules

Answer (score 3):

Since the question mentions numpy, here is a solution without using loops:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[3.,4.,5.],[1.,2.,3.]])
a = a/a[:,0:1]
print a
```

gives the required result

```
array([[ 1.        ,  1.33333333,  1.66666667],
       [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ]])
```

There are a few subtleties here:

1. I am using floats instead of integers to avoid surprises with integer division when using Python 2
2. You have to use `a[:,0:1]` instead of `a[:,0]` to select the first column
3. You can't write `a /= a[:,0:1]` since the in-place operators treat array broadcasting differently for some reason

Comment: +1 for using numpy. This is the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `x` fixed for the whole loop, just set its value before you go into the loop:

```
x = a[0][0] 
for i in a[0]:
    a[0][n] = a[0][n]/x 
    print a[0][n]
    n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
a = [[3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]

b = [[float(i)/row[0] for i in row] for row in a]
```